# Terminal commands and c++ system(...) command return different results

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, command

I am on OSX.
This is my C++ code:

```
char * lCommandChar = lCommand;
std::cout << lCommandChar << std::endl;
int lSystRep = system(lCommandChar);
```

The console display:

```
echo -n "d2b16b956644ba30a73e9b116a4a4f4099add017" | /usr/bin/openssl dgst -verify /Users/me/opm.public -sha1 -signature /Users/me/Library/Caches/OrchPlay/temp_sig.bin
Verification Failure
```

If I open the Terminal and copy the previous log I got:

```
$ echo -n "d2b16b956644ba30a73e9b116a4a4f4099add017" | /usr/bin/openssl dgst -verify /Users/me/opm.public -sha1 -signature /Users/me/Library/Caches/OrchPlay/temp_sig.bin
Verified OK
```

Where can be the difference between the 2 system calls?

Edit: I finally used the -d to display the debug output, I could see a difference apparently related to reading the signature:
My code returns:

```
BIO[6100000C01read(0,8192) - FILE pointer
BIO[6100000C01read return 44
```

The terminal returns:

```
BIO[7FB060C152read(0,8192) - FILE pointer
BIO[7FB060C152read return 40
```

But I still don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you check the user rights? Maybe your app isn't allowed to access one of the files...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be related to that.

Comment: Which output do you get in both cases when you add the switch "-verbose" to your openssl command?

Comment: Try changing `openssl` to `/usr/bin/openssl` in both.

Comment: Also add the `-config` command line switch with the path to the correct config.

Comment: I tried to specify the path, no success. As for the -config command, I don't understand how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing the "echo -n" by a "printf" and it worked. printf seems more reliable : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

```
printf "d2b16b956644ba30a73e9b116a4a4f4099add017" | /usr/bin/openssl dgst -verify /Users/me/opm.public -sha1 -signature /Users/me/Library/Caches/OrchPlay/temp_sig.bin
Verified OK
```